Absolute Imports with '@' on CRA is not working
I try to migrate the app from relative imports to absolute imports. According to CRA docs I add these piece of code to my tsconfig.json file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl: "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

This setup is works nice like:
import MyComponent from "components/MyCopmonent"
But I want to set imports with '@' like this:
import MyComponent from "@components/MyComponent"

I assume you are trying to set up path aliases, so you need to configure them as such
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".", // Root of your paths
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"] // enables to use @components/MyComponent
    }
  }
}

